# android studio show widgets on an home made launcher created in java android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, widget

For now I succeeded to create a launcher that can start apps but to make it better, I would like to know if it's possible to show on my app the widgets of other apps such as the weather.

Thanks for helping

This is what it looks like today
[what my app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J69tc.jpg)
This is what my launcher looks like I would like to also show the weather widget or the clock widget has shown below
on another launcher.

In fact I want that the app that I made in Android Studio is able to show the clock widget that you can see on the second image named 'traditional launcher'

[traditional launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZRQY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To create a simple widgets follow these steps:

##### Create Layout and call it camera_widget

Go to `res/layout/camera_widget.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#ff8533"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Scatta video o foto da qui"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:padding="8dp"
android:textSize="18sp"/>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp">
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="-"
android:background="#44ff8533"
android:padding="8dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_movie_creation_black_24dp"
android:id="@+id/btn_video"/>
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#44ff8533"
android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp"
android:id="@+id/btn_photo"
android:padding="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Next, you need to create a Java class that extends AppWidgetProvider, consisting of a sort of evolved BroadcastReceiver, which we must therefore register in the ApplicationManifest.xml file - within the `<application>` block - as follows:

```
<receiver android:name=".CameraWidget">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/camera_widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

where the `name` attribute specifies the implementation class of the App Widget, the `intent-filter` block establishes the event that will "wake it up" as an extension of a BroadcastReceiver, while the other internal meta-data block specifies the file configuration that we will find among the XML resources.

The `camera_widget_info` configuration file in our example is as follows:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/camera_widget"
android:initialLayout="@layout/camera_widget"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minWidth="180dp"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
android:previewImage="@drawable/screenshot"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"/>
```

In it, we find specified minimum dimensions, direction of manual expansion of the widget as well as the preview image that operates. in the App Widget manager The updatePeriodMillis attribute is also present, which indicates how many milliseconds the widget must be updated: the official documentation however specifies that this update will not be allowed more than once every half hour.

##### The following is the code of the

`CameraWidget.class`:

```
class CameraWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun updateAppWidget(
            context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
            appWidgetId: Int
        ) {
// (1) carica layout nella RemoteViews
            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.camera_widget)
            // (2.1) gestione click su pulsante che attiva video
            val videoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0,
                videoIntent, 0
            )
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_video, pendingIntent)
            // (2.2) gestione click su pulsante che attiva foto
            val photoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA)
            val pendingIntentContact = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0,
                photoIntent, 0
            )
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_photo, pendingIntentContact)
            // (3) AppWidgetManager assegna la RemoteViews all'App Widget con id appWidgetId
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }
}
```

The onUpdate method is invoked in response to the `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` and `ACTION_APPWIDGET_RESTORED` broadcasts and is aimed at updating the View. Note that in input it receives, among other things, a reference to the `Context` and an array of integers containing the identifiers of the App Widgets of that class that must receive the update. Inside it, we will do nothing but execute a loop on all the reported ids and, for each of them, we will invoke the `updateAppWidget` method.

Comment: This code is to create a widget that will be seen on a launcher? But what I want to do is to show the widget of another app. For example I want that on the screen of my app I can show the weather widgets. thanks for the help

Comment: I thought you wanted to create it.
Do you have a sample app, or an image that makes me understand what you are looking for? Because if you talk about widgets you are talking about additional objects to your app, not about other people's apps. But maybe I don't understand the question

Comment: I edited my question, I hop that it can help you :-)